# Large Virtual Memory Size usage

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, psutil

Good day.

I am wondering why by starting new process using `subprocess.Popen` and asking `psutil.Process.memory_info()` for Virtual Memory size I am getting more than 21 megabytes? (in script that is started by `Popen`  simply prints data read from stdin that is passed by main script)

**main.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import sys, psutil, shlex

with Popen(shlex.split('python3 ./test.py'), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT) as proc:

main_stdin = sys.stdin.read()
print('Writting main STDIN stream:', main_stdin)
proc.stdin.write(bytes(main_stdin, 'UTF-8')) # "redirect" main's stdin to test's stdin

mem_info = psutil.Process(proc.pid).memory_info()
print('RSS:', mem_info.rss/1048576) # bytes to megabytes
print('VMS:', mem_info.vms/1048576)

sub_stdout = proc.communicate()[0].decode('UTF-8')
print('Reading sub STDOUT: ', sub_stdout)
```

**test.py**

```
from sys import stdin

print(stdin.read())
```

Ubuntu 14.04, Python 3.4

Thank you!